# Retaining an NSWindow size and state - looking for an elegant way to do this

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a controller class which spawns a window when a certain condition occurs. This window can be closed by the user, moved around or resized.

Ideally, when this condition occurs, I'd like the window to re-open in the same spot the user closed it last time.

Looking for an elegant way to do this. Pointers (or references) will be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, AppKit knows this is a common pattern and has provided `-setFrameAutosaveName:`, which does this automatically for you. (If you're using `NSWindowController` you'll want to call `setShouldCascadeWindows:NO`, which will override this.)

Comment: I create and launch my window from my controller without a XIB file. How can I "check" if there's a saved value and "apply" it myself when I create the window?

Comment: You don't need to. `-setFrameAutosaveName:` does the checking and applying for you. Just call the method at some point after creating it.