# Retaining the constants of NSLayoutConstraints

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nslayoutconstraint

In Pre-NSLayoutConstraint times, this was possible with `NSWindow`:
[Retaining an NSWindow size and state - looking for an elegant way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478185/retaining-an-nswindow-size-and-state-looking-for-an-elegant-way-to-do-this)

Is there a way to save the `NSLayoutConstraint.constant`s on application quit, and restore them again on launch?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit of a far reach, but I think you could use **NSCoding** for this.